# Is it ever correct to use ANOVA for multiple dependent variables?

Tags: anova, forecasting, manova

Is it correct to use ANOVA on data that has multiple variables? I have a table with four variables which represent four methods of forecasting, the table also comprises of Bullwhip effect results calculated for each of these methods. The main objective is to find out whether there was a difference in the forecasting methods impact on the bullwhip effect. I have tried to use repeated measure ANOVA and i got a result, my question is, am i using an appropriate test of ANOVA?

Comment: What's a bullwhip effect? Which repeated measure ANOVA statistic are you using (there are a few)? Are you asking about ANOVA or repeated measures ANOVA? If the latter, you should change your question.

Comment: @Tim, my question is whether using repeated measures is best for this type of scenario. I am using One-way repeated measures ANOVA. Bullwhip effect refers to increasing swings in inventory in response to shifts in customer demand as one moves further up the supply chain.

Comment: Not sure. I am still a bit confused.